# more command not found in Cygwin

Tags: bash, cygwin

I typed this command as mentioned in my book. I don't see any output. Instead, I get an error:

```
ls -l|more
-bash: more: command not found
```

How can I fix this problem? The same thing happens for the `lp` command.

Answer (score 4):

`more` is available on Cygwin via the `util-linux` package. However, most people today use `less` instead, which is more powerful.

There is no `lp` in Cygwin, though you can get `lpr` via the `cygutils` package.

You can search http://cygwin.com/packages/ to find out which package (if any) contains a specific program.

However, in general, you shouldn't expect Cygwin to support all the commands you'd find in a typical Linux distribution. If you want to experiment with Linux on a Windows machine, I'd suggest actually running Linux in a virtual machine (e.g., using something like [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)).

Comment: Cygwin does have `more`, in [`util-linux`](http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=util-linux%2Futil-linux-2.17.2-1).

Comment: I stand corrected, thanks. It's not installed by default, though.

Comment: @slhck - how do i install it ? Can I run bash commands on ubuntu 12.x ?

Comment: bashgirl: just use the cygwin setup.

Comment: @ott-- yes. i typed lp and more into the search bar of setup and got some strange looking results. In lp, there were so many results, I don't know which one to use. Btw, bash girl ? Haha...looks like unix is not the only thing going on in your mind right now :)

Comment: Updated the answer. BTW, none of these programs you're referring to are "bash commands". They're separate programs that you can run via `bash`. Ubuntu would be a fine choice for experimenting.